# Which version of the Xcode installed which simulator？

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I had Xcode and Xcode-beta and I want to know which version of the Xcode installed which simulate. Is there any way to implement it with code or any relations between them?

Comment: You should be able to find out the version of xcode simulator from the top bar or use menu iOS Simulator -> About iOS Simulator

Comment: Is there any way to implement it with code?

Comment: No there isn't. Xcode is just an IDE.

Comment: Well...thanks any way~

Comment: why do you want to know this, anyways?  The behavior of the iOS 8.4 simulator in Xcode-beta.app (Xcode 7 beta) should be the exact same as the iOS 8.4 simulator from Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Just a bit inquisitive about how Xcode find simulators for itself.